# Is there any real route of appeal on a ban because of an overstay in Thailand?

Tags: visas, thailand, overstaying

Even though I am a property owner there and had a valid visa still in date, when I exited Bangkok for the U.K., I was heavily fined but, much worse, was banned for one year as I had not left the Kingdom after 90 days and then re-entered.

As I have many commitments there including a property, and my worldy goods, it is a much more serious matter than if I was just holidaying there.

Does any one know of an appeal that has been successful, in getting their case reviewed?

Comment: I think your explanations just make things worse. You entered on a tourist visa and tried to become a resident.

Comment: If you were allowed to appeal on grounds of "Oh, it was an honest mistake -- I just miscounted the days", _everybody_ would do that. And, as @ugoren says, your situation is almost certainly made _worse_ by using visa-free tourist entry as a means to build up a life in Thailand.

Comment: It may have been a non-immigrant business or work visa rather than a tourist visa. That is consistent with being permitted to stay for 90 days at a time, and to extend by a visa run.

Comment: how long ago was this? how old are you?  when you say you had valid visa, was your `permission to stay` (stamped in passport and departure card) still valid?  if you had multiple entry visa, did you attempt to do out-in border run?